# CkEditor doesn't immediately run ACF

Tags: ckeditor

If I try to getData() immediately after I setData(), the contents have not yet been filtered. How can I get the post-filtered contents programmatically?

See this JSFiddle for a very simple repro.  By clicking the 'source' after the 'test' button, you can see that the filter is eventually run.
https://jsfiddle.net/L8kb4nes/7/ (ignore string concat used to get around jsfiddle limitations)

```
editor.setData('<p>Hi There!</p><script></script>');
$('#output').text(editor.getData());
//Outputs '<p>Hi There!</p><script></script>'
//Source button shows '<p>Hi There!</p>'
```

Answer (score 1):

While the documentation doesn't describe this, setData() is actually asynchronous.

ckeditor has several events that you can listen to, '[dataReady](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-dataReady)' is explicitly in response to the setData() method (it does not fire after user input), while '[change](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-change)' is fired after setData AND user input.

Sample code to get the modified data after set:

```
editor.setData('<p>Hi There!</p><script></script>');
editor.once('dataReady', function(){
    $('#output').text(editor.getData());
});
```